# ScrollTo and ScrollToExact equivalent for webView in appium for android

Tags: android, testing, webview, automated-tests, appium

I am automating android app using appium (java).
For scrolling on native components, I use `scrollTo()` and `scrollToExact()` methods.
But in case of webView inside the app ; these methods are not working.

**UPDATE:**
I have tried these two methods also:

```
public static void scrollNavigation(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> wd, String widID, String target, String direction)
    {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) wd;
        HashMap<String, String> swipeObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
        swipeObject.put("text", target);
        swipeObject.put("direction", direction);
        swipeObject.put("element", widID);
        js.executeScript("mobile: scrollTo", swipeObject);
        wait(200);
    }

    public static void swipeUpElement(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver, MobileElement element, int duration)
    {
        int topY = element.getLocation().getY();
        int bottomY = topY + element.getSize().getHeight();
        int centerX = element.getLocation().getX() + (element.getSize().getWidth()/2);
        driver.swipe(centerX, bottomY, centerX, topY, duration);
    }
```

But in both these I need element- but on the page I cannot find any element except the webview.
I am using UiAutomator to capture the IDs.
Any suggestions / link / workaround will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ELements arent displaced uniquely in web view. U need to develop mathematical logic to get screen size and scroll according to them, use the below code,

```
public void scroll() throws IOException {
          try {
            Dimension dimensions = driver.manage().window().getSize();
            System.out.println("Size of Window= " +dimension);
            int scrollStart = (int) (dimension.getHeight() * 0.5);
            System.out.println("Size of scrollStart= " +scrollStart);
            int scrollEnd = (int) (dimension.getHeight() * 0.2);
            System.out.println("Size of cscrollEnd= " + scrollEnd);             
            driver.swipe(0,scrollStart,0,scrollEnd,1000);           
            Application_Log.info("Screen Swiped " );            
            
            } catch (IOException e) {
                
                Assert.fail("Swipe failed");
            }
            
      }
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this,by the way IOException?will it throw IOException ever?

Comment: I am bit confused how to scroll particular dimension using this method,just a small help would be helpful

Comment: @AnswerDroid    'code'  Dimension dimensions = driver.manage().window().getSize(); Will get the screen size. U can manipulate the particular dimesion you want by editing scrollstart and scrollEnd multiplication factor

Comment: ok, i will try. this will work on both screens? native and hybrid? thanks

Comment: Yes..this is generic by just taking the device screen dimension

Comment: Yes..this is generic by just taking the device screen dimension

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101363/discussion-between-answerdroid-and-karthick23).

Comment: It's not good practice to throw exceptions from methods unless you intend the client to handle them, especially if you already handle them inside the method. Just tacking a `throws` clause onto a method without thought is careless engineering. Think: What should the client code do with the exception? How will it have enough context for troubleshooting if you rise through the stack before noticing it?

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to native context `driver.context("NATIVE_APP");` before scroll .
If it does not work then give a try for `JavascriptExecutor` like below sample

```
MobileElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("element-xpath"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
HashMap scrollObject = new HashMap();
scrollObject.put("direction", "down");
scrollObject.put("element", element);
js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);
```

Comment: what is element here? I mean suppose I have to scroll to Text field with hint Password.then how should I call the above code.?Thanks a lot

Comment: If you have id for Text Field or xpath then element is  MobileElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("text-field-id"));

Comment: I am not getting any id -Inside this - android.webkit.WebView , nothing gets captured in UIAutomator

Comment: You need to switch to webview. Manually try to tap on webview .It happened with as well sometimes. Then refresh UIAutomator

Comment: This is not working swami , any other way?I have updated my question on whatever I've tried so far